# WordPress: Error while importing Trait inside Class

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using WordPress rest api, and I have created a custom theme, and I want to code using OOP. And I'm having issues importing a Trait inside a Class.

here is the code:

MyController class

```php
<?php

namespace Controllers;

use Controllers\RespondsWithHttpStatus;

class MyController {
  use RespondsWithHttpStatus;

  public function __construct() {}

  public function hello() {
    return "hello world";
  }

}
```

RespondsWithHttpStatus trait

```php
<?php

namespace Controllers;

trait RespondsWithHttpStatus
{

    protected function success($message, $data = [], $status = 200)
    {
        return array([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $data,
            'message' => $message,
            'timestamp' => current_time( 'timestamp', 1)
        ], $status);
    }


    protected function failure($message, $status = 422)
    {
        return array([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $message,
            'timestamp' => current_time( 'timestamp', 1)
        ], $status);
    }

}
```

functions.php

```php
<?php

require_once('Controllers/MyController.php';

add_action('rest_api_init', 'greet');

 function greet() {
    register_rest_route('greet/v1', 'greet', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'greeting'
    ));
 }

 function greeting() {
     $myController = new MyController();
     return $myController->hello();
 }
```

What is causing the problem is "use RespondsWithHttpStatus" field in MyController Class, I have tried to use namespaces and use keyword, but without luck.

Comment: Are you actually getting an error? Are you including the trait file code somewhere, too?

Comment: WordPress is showing this msg: "There has been a critical error on this website" without telling me what is exactly the issue, and no, I'm not using the the trait somewhere else.

Comment: Turn on WP_DEBUG. My second question was whether you are including the trait which is not shown. PHP will not scour the file system for any files unless you build an auto loader.

Comment: ok thanks you, I was including the trait in the class using "use RespondsWithHttpStatus" and also I was decalring at the top a namespace "custom\Controllers", because the class and the trait are in this path themes/custom/controllers

Comment: PHP’s relationship with the file system is often misunderstood, probably because most modern code has an auto loader, and most code samples assume you are using one. I’d look into that. It even works in a WordPress context, but I’d strongly recommend looking into namespaces then.

Comment: after enabling WP_DEBUG I have this error "Fatal error: Trait 'Controllers\RespondsWithHttpStatus' not found in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/custom/Controllers/MyController.php"

Comment: To be specific, you need to `require`, `include` or similar that file.

Comment: Thank you so much, require_once('RespondsWithHttpStatus.php'); in MyController solved the issue. You can include this as a response so I can validate it.

Comment: Go ahead and post as your own answer. I’m on an iPad and it is harder to write code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `require_once('RespondsWithHttpStatus.php');` in MyController.php solved the issue.